Error visualize lidar data in rviz
I'm using gazebo ignition fortress and ros2 humble to simulate lidar data. It works fine in ignition

But in rviz it show nothing and i get this:

I'm thinking that the problem is in my lidar.xacro file. When i comment this line
 <!-- <gz_frame_id>laser_frame<gz_frame_id> -->

the result like above.
When i uncomment it, rviz works but ignition gazebo get error


Thanks for reading and please comment if you know anything i can do to fix this
Here is the full code of my lidar.xacro file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" >
    <joint name="laser_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="chassis_link"/>
        <child link="laser_frame"/>
        <origin xyz="0.2 0 0.12" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="laser_frame">
        
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.04"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="mycolor"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.04"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="0.04" radius="0.05">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference="laser_frame">

        <sensor name='laser' type='gpu_lidar'>"
        <pose relative_to='laser_frame'>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <topic>scan</topic>
        <update_rate>10</update_rate>
        <ray>
            <scan>
                <horizontal>
                    <samples>360</samples>
                    <resolution>1</resolution>
                    <min_angle>-3.14</min_angle>
                    <max_angle>3.14</max_angle>
                </horizontal>
                <vertical>
                    <samples>1</samples>
                    <resolution>0.01</resolution>
                    <min_angle>0</min_angle>
                    <max_angle>0</max_angle>
                </vertical>
            </scan>
            <range>
                <min>0.3</min>
                <max>5.0</max>
                <resolution>0.01</resolution>
            </range>
        </ray>
        <always_on>1</always_on>
        <visualize>true</visualize>
        <gz_frame_id>laser_frame</gz_frame_id>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>
</robot>

[update] assiociated frame_id related to /scan topic



Edit: I add another link and lidar sensor duplicate with current one, 1 comment and one don't the line <gz_frame_id>laser_frame</gz_frame_id> and it fine on both rviz and ignition but i don't think that's a good solution.
I defined the laser_frame link in urdf so it must be appear in tf tree
and the transform from scan topic should be alright.


Welcome to Robotics, Wildfear. What topic are you using for publishing points? In the screenshot where rviz is not showing points, you're showing console output stating messages are being dropped for my_bot/base_link/laser, but in the screenshot where rviz is showing points the topic there is /scan. I don't see anything in the documentation you've provided that would use the my_bot/base_link/laser topic. In the screenshot where rviz isn't showing anything, you're using base_link as the fixed frame but I don't see that in your snippets. Can you please clarify how these are published?

Hi @Chuck
For your first question: What topic are you using for publishing points?
I'm using a bridge from /scan topic in ignition gazebo to /scan topic in ros2 to publish points.                      your second question: Can you please clarify how these are published?
i use robot_state_publisher node to publish to xacro file to topic /robot_description and use ros_gz_sim package with create command to spawn model in ignition gazebo. I noticed that there no entity named my_bot although it should.

sorry i'm wrong. Actually there is my_bot entity in world. I found that my_bot/base_link/laser is a frame, not a topic and it's represent in gazebo and rviz can't see it. Maybe this is the problem?

Yeah, might be the problem. The /scan topic should also have an associated frame_id; what is that value? Is that frame published in a way that rviz can consume? Something like a URDF or a /tf message.

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. I updated images about view_frames, rqt_graph command and a image that the /scan topic in gazebo is associated with /my_bot/base_link/laser frame in gazebo.
Can you check it out and tell me what's wrong

I mean if you rostopic echo /scan or ros2 topic echo /scan you should see a header with a frame_id field. What is that frame_id, and do you have it published? You added a graphic under, "associated frame_id related to /scan topic," but the image there shows a laser and laser_2. In the tf graph at the bottom of your post, you don't have these frames, you have laser_frame and laser_frame_2. What frame are you expecting the data to come on, and how are you publishing that frame?

laser and laser_2 are names of lidar sensor denifed under  tag, it not a frame, right? I realize that the problem is:
when i use <gz_frame_id>laser_frame</gz_frame_id> tag, it sets the frame_id of topic /scan to laser_frame so it can be display in rviz without problem but it error in ignition because the frame_id of /scan should be /world/map/model/laser_frame

I expect data come from laser_frame and i publish it by putting sensor tag under <gazebo reference="laser_frame"> tag

It sounds like you either need to change the gz_frame_id to /world/map/model/laser_frame and publish a transform for that frame so rviz can use it, or you can keep using the laser_frame and change ignition to expect data on that topic instead.
